# My desktop application hangs on web API service call with async and await

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am getting lots of delay when saving data in database. I have one  exe (Deskptop Application) which reads data from serial port and push that entry in to database through web API service but my application get hangs on this line:

```
httpClient.PostAsync("api/MyController/Save", httpConent).Result;
```

This exe is responsible to call my web API service method and save data to my database.

This is my code:

```
void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
       {
           int dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
           byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
           int nbrDataRead = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);

           if (nbrDataRead == 0)
               return;

           // Send data to whom ever interested
           if (NewSerialDataRecieved != null)
           {
               NewSerialDataRecieved(this, new SerialDataEventArgs(data));
           }
       }

 void _spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                // Using this.Invoke causes deadlock when closing serial port, and BeginInvoke is good practice anyway.
                //// Fired-off asynchronously; let the current thread continue.
                this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<SerialDataEventArgs>(_spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved), new object[] { sender, e });
                return;
            }
            //data is converted to text
            string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Data);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
               CallWebservice(str)
            }
        }

public void CallWebservice(string xmlRequest)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
               httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("WebService Url");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                StringContent httpConent = new StringContent(xmlRequest, Encoding.UTF8);
                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
                try
                {
                    responseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync("api/MyController/Save", httpConent).Result;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (responseMessage == null)
                    {
                        responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
                    }
                    responseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    responseMessage.ReasonPhrase = string.Format("RestHttpClient.SendRequest failed: {0}", ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

My web api method:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Save(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
               var requestdata = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;//extract Users Id's from this
                var users=context.User.Where(t => (t.Stats == userId1) || (t.Stats == userId2)).ToList();
                var objUsersMapping= new UsersMapping();
                objUsersMapping.Work1 = users[0].Work1;
                objUsersMapping.Work2 = users[1].Work1;
                await this.SaveUsersMapping(objUsersMapping); 
        }

 public async Task<UsersMapping> SaveUsersMapping(UsersMapping objUsersMapping)
        {
            using (var context = new MyEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    context.UsersMapping.Add(objUsersMapping);
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return objUsersMapping;
                }
                catch (Exception foExe)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

I haven't work much on Windows application so I am not understanding why my application is hanging.

**Note**: data will be continuously coming to my serial port so saving data through web service should not disturb `_serialPort_DataReceived` event.

Comment: You are calling an asynchronous method **synchronously**.  Get rid of the `.Result` and alter the rest of the code accordingly (like including `async` and `await` there too)

Comment: @MickyD:Thank you for the quick response.Is this the only problem sir??

Comment: No problem. You should fix your async `Save()` method on the server too as it **also** has a `.Result()`.  That will block the current thread on the server.  Prefix it with a `await`.   Generally you want to avoid `.Result` as a means to wait for the task to complete.  It is safe to use as a means to obtain the result after you have awaited it, but there are more elegant ways to await and get the result in a single line of code

Comment: @MickyD:But getting error when i do like this:await httpClient.PostAsync("api/MyController/Save", httpConent);Await can only be used with async method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

---

This is a summary of my comments beneath the OP's question

---

You are calling an asynchronous method synchronously. That will cause the current thread to block.  Get rid of the `.Result` and alter the rest of the code accordingly (like including `async` and `await` there too).

e.g.  change this line

```
responseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync("api/MyController/Save", httpConent).Result;
```

...to:

```
 responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("api/MyController/Save", httpConent);
```

Your method signature will need to be changed as follows:

```
public async Task CallWebservice(string xmlRequest)
{

}
```

Any method that calls it will also need to be `async` and use `await` for example your `_spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved()` method.

Note it has been changed from `void` to `async void`.  Note too the `await` prior to `CallWebservice()`.

```
async void _spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            // Using this.Invoke causes deadlock when closing serial port, and BeginInvoke is good practice anyway.
            //// Fired-off asynchronously; let the current thread continue.
            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<SerialDataEventArgs>(_spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved), new object[] { sender, e });
            return;
        }
        //data is converted to text
        string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Data);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
           await CallWebservice(str)
        }
    }
```

### A note on async void

Because the above method is an event handler it is fine for the method to be `async void`.  Generally you want to avoid `async void` in **non** event handler code.  For more info see [this brilliant article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) by Mr Stephen Cleary.

> Is this the only problem sir??

You should fix your `async Save()` method on the server too as it also has a `.Result()`. That will block the current thread on the server. Prefix it with a `await`. Generally you want to avoid `.Result` *as a means to wait for the task to complete*. It is safe to use as a means to obtain the *result* after you have awaited it, but there are more elegant ways to await and get the result in a single line of code.  e.g. `x = await FooAsync();`.

Comment: CallWebservice is called from _spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved method.So i should make it async too??

Comment: But this.BeginInvoke already does this:please read my comments that i have written on that

Comment: @Learning So? That has nothing to do with `async`.  You're merely marshalling a call to the UI thread from a worker thread. You are still making a synchronous call to the web service and blocking the UI thread until it completes

Comment: var data = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();.To read data in web api is this correct??

Comment: @Learning That's the ticket

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112032/discussion-between-learning-and-mickyd).

Comment: @Learning (wanted to add this to chat)  Great to hear everything is working now good buddy. :D

Comment: Yes and all this credit goes to you.if you have not answer then I might have badly struggling with this for sure